# usermod не добавляет пользователя в группу

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Добавляю своего пользователя (`w3lifer`) в группу `www-data`:

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data w3lifer
```

Проверяю:

```
groups www-data
```

Нету (www-data : www-data). Перезагружаю комп — то же самое: нету в группе.

Почему?

[image: usermod не добавляет пользователя в группу]

Comment: `groups w3lifer`

Comment: @andreymal, что именно? Вы имеете в виду, что `groups <user>` показывает в каких группах состоит юзер?

Comment: Да, об этом написано в самом начале справки команды groups

Comment: @andreymal, блин,.. а я чего-то думал, что она показывает название группы и всех юзеров, которые в ней состоят.

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ из комментария @andreymal.

`groups <user>` показывает в каких группах состоит юзер, а не название группы и всех юзеров, которые в ней состоят.